# why does my Android Studio Project not have "androidTest"and "test" folder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-testing

I'm trying to practice testing on andoid studio. I'm following a Android [Developer tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation#9). But I noticed my project doesn't have the `androidTest` folder or the `test`. It only has the main folder.

Here's what I mean:

[image: Image of Android Studio Directory Lacking androidTest and Test folder]

I tried to rebuild project, that didn't help. Please I would appreciate any help. And I'll be happy to provide any information needed.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring androidTest and Test packages again.

only usage

[image]

java - right click - package and androidTest or unitTest select.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Thanks for your help Arda. I just tried doing this, but it only created a new pacakage "androidTest".

Comment: Hello @Edwin, try again but now selecting unitTest package instead of androidTest